# Find start date and end date of non zero rows r dataframe and create a table

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

rh1 is the sample price dataframe
rh2 is returns of rh1 and return_cum is the cumulative returns of rh2 and ret_drawdown computes drawdown.

```
library(xts)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
set.seed(1)
rh1 = xts(cbind(a=c(100,101,103,97,101,98,86,112,109,112)) , Sys.Date()+1:10 )
rh2 =na.omit(Return.calculate(rh1[-1],method = "discrete"))
return_cum = cumprod(1+rh2)
ret_drawdown = 1- (return_cum/cummax(return_cum))
```

ret_drawdown looks as follows:-

```
2021-02-14 0.0000
2021-02-15 0.0583
2021-02-16 0.0194
2021-02-17 0.0485
2021-02-18 0.1650
2021-02-19 0.0000
2021-02-20 0.0268
2021-02-21 0.0000
```

I want a table as follows:-

```
start date end date   cumulative returns
2021-02-15 2021-02-18 (sum of return values for this period: 0.0583+0.0194+0.0485+0.165)
2021-02-20 2021-02-20  0.0268
```

This table consists of occurance of non zero entries from ret_drawdown dataframe. Please suggest the way forward

Answer below works for the data above.
However for ret_drawdown as the following data, it fails

```
2010-01-07 0.00e+00
2010-01-08 5.67e-03
2010-01-11 1.17e-02
2010-01-12 1.23e-02
2010-01-13 1.37e-02
2010-01-14 1.52e-02
2010-01-15 7.57e-03
2010-01-18 1.09e-02
2010-01-19 5.30e-03
2010-01-20 0.00e+00
2010-01-21 2.30e-04
2010-01-22 7.79e-04
2010-01-25 1.89e-03
2010-01-26 0.00e+00
2010-01-27 0.00e+00
2010-01-28 0.00e+00
2010-01-29 0.00e+00
2010-02-01 2.77e-03
2010-02-02 5.64e-03
2010-02-03 1.13e-03
2010-02-04 0.00e+00
2010-02-05 0.00e+00
2010-02-08 1.73e-03
2010-02-09 7.19e-03
2010-02-10 5.13e-03
2010-02-11 5.56e-03
2010-02-12 2.77e-03
2010-02-15 1.36e-03
2010-02-16 9.21e-03
2010-02-17 8.08e-04
2010-02-18 5.35e-04
2010-02-19 0.00e+00
2010-02-22 1.69e-03
2010-02-23 0.00e+00
2010-02-24 1.24e-05
2010-02-25 7.79e-04
2010-02-26 6.04e-03
2010-03-01 2.37e-03
2010-03-02 4.07e-03
2010-03-03 1.08e-02
2010-03-04 3.57e-03
2010-03-05 5.17e-03
2010-03-08 5.17e-03
2010-03-09 3.19e-03
2010-03-10 5.01e-03
2010-03-11 6.52e-03
2010-03-12 1.26e-02
2010-03-15 7.41e-03
2010-03-16 1.36e-02
2010-03-17 1.50e-02
2010-03-18 7.73e-03
2010-03-19 1.56e-03
2010-03-22 2.46e-03
2010-03-23 0.00e+00
2010-03-24 0.00e+00
2010-03-25 0.00e+00
2010-03-26 5.41e-03
2010-03-29 9.28e-03
2010-03-30 7.92e-03
2010-03-31 1.27e-02
2010-04-01 1.64e-02
2010-04-02 1.15e-02
2010-04-05 1.25e-02
2010-04-06 8.93e-03
2010-04-07 8.24e-03
2010-04-08 7.14e-03
2010-04-09 1.25e-02
2010-04-12 1.90e-02
2010-04-13 1.96e-02
2010-04-14 2.35e-02
2010-04-15 1.99e-02
2010-04-16 1.58e-02
2010-04-19 1.36e-02
2010-04-20 1.30e-02
2010-04-21 1.17e-02
2010-04-22 6.73e-03
2010-04-23 9.35e-03
2010-04-26 7.78e-03
2010-04-27 0.00e+00
2010-04-28 0.00e+00
2010-04-29 4.59e-03
2010-04-30 6.25e-03
2010-05-03 1.32e-03
2010-05-04 0.00e+00
2010-05-05 0.00e+00
2010-05-06 0.00e+00
2010-05-07 5.23e-03
2010-05-10 8.69e-03
2010-05-11 5.03e-03
2010-05-12 7.77e-04
2010-05-13 0.00e+00
2010-05-14 0.00e+00
2010-05-17 0.00e+00
2010-05-18 0.00e+00
2010-05-19 8.83e-03
2010-05-20 1.83e-02
2010-05-21 2.05e-02
2010-05-24 1.10e-02
2010-05-25 4.39e-03
2010-05-26 4.70e-04
2010-05-27 1.12e-02
2010-05-28 7.82e-03
2010-05-31 6.59e-03
2010-06-01 5.95e-03
2010-06-02 4.23e-03
2010-06-03 2.98e-04
2010-06-04 0.00e+00
2010-06-07 0.00e+00
2010-06-08 1.24e-04
2010-06-09 5.75e-03
2010-06-10 1.40e-02
2010-06-11 1.02e-02
2010-06-14 2.14e-02
2010-06-15 2.74e-02
2010-06-16 2.63e-02
2010-06-17 3.07e-02
2010-06-18 3.06e-02
2010-06-21 2.80e-02
2010-06-22 2.60e-02
2010-06-23 3.01e-02
2010-06-24 3.02e-02
2010-06-25 3.50e-02
2010-06-28 3.11e-02
2010-06-29 2.69e-02
2010-06-30 2.70e-02
2010-07-01 4.17e-02
2010-07-02 4.50e-02
2010-07-05 4.30e-02
2010-07-06 4.89e-02
2010-07-07 5.18e-02
2010-07-08 5.18e-02
2010-07-09 5.04e-02
2010-07-12 4.75e-02
2010-07-13 5.39e-02
2010-07-14 5.63e-02
2010-07-15 6.61e-02
2010-07-16 6.70e-02
2010-07-19 6.66e-02
2010-07-20 6.40e-02
2010-07-21 5.67e-02
2010-07-22 6.57e-02
2010-07-23 6.72e-02
2010-07-26 7.15e-02
2010-07-27 7.04e-02
2010-07-28 7.04e-02
2010-07-29 7.66e-02
2010-07-30 7.77e-02
2010-08-02 8.45e-02
2010-08-03 8.83e-02
2010-08-04 8.50e-02
2010-08-05 8.57e-02
2010-08-06 9.05e-02
2010-08-09 8.70e-02
2010-08-10 8.60e-02
2010-08-11 6.92e-02
2010-08-12 6.53e-02
2010-08-13 6.17e-02
2010-08-16 6.64e-02
2010-08-17 6.99e-02
2010-08-18 6.99e-02
2010-08-19 6.74e-02
2010-08-20 6.05e-02
2010-08-23 5.97e-02
2010-08-24 5.95e-02
2010-08-25 5.82e-02
2010-08-26 6.19e-02
2010-08-27 6.21e-02
2010-08-30 5.93e-02
2010-08-31 5.89e-02
2010-09-01 6.65e-02
2010-09-02 6.72e-02
2010-09-03 7.13e-02
2010-09-06 7.20e-02
2010-09-07 6.32e-02
2010-09-08 6.58e-02
2010-09-09 6.48e-02
2010-09-10 6.46e-02
2010-09-13 7.34e-02
2010-09-14 8.29e-02
2010-09-15 7.82e-02
2010-09-16 8.10e-02
2010-09-17 7.93e-02
2010-09-20 8.00e-02
2010-09-21 9.01e-02
2010-09-22 9.70e-02
2010-09-23 9.50e-02
2010-09-24 1.02e-01
2010-09-27 1.03e-01
2010-09-28 1.06e-01
2010-09-29 1.10e-01
2010-09-30 1.10e-01
2010-10-01 1.17e-01
2010-10-04 1.13e-01
2010-10-05 1.21e-01
2010-10-06 1.25e-01
2010-10-07 1.25e-01
2010-10-08 1.25e-01
2010-10-11 1.24e-01
2010-10-12 1.25e-01
2010-10-13 1.28e-01
2010-10-14 1.33e-01
2010-10-15 1.29e-01
2010-10-18 1.30e-01
2010-10-19 1.16e-01
2010-10-20 1.27e-01
2010-10-21 1.24e-01
2010-10-22 1.24e-01
2010-10-25 1.28e-01
2010-10-26 1.21e-01
2010-10-27 1.16e-01
2010-10-28 1.26e-01
2010-10-29 1.26e-01
2010-11-01 1.26e-01
2010-11-02 1.32e-01
2010-11-03 1.35e-01
2010-11-04 1.42e-01
2010-11-05 1.34e-01
2010-11-08 1.29e-01
2010-11-09 1.24e-01
2010-11-10 1.22e-01
2010-11-11 1.15e-01
2010-11-12 1.17e-01
2010-11-15 1.12e-01
2010-11-16 1.04e-01
2010-11-17 1.05e-01
2010-11-18 1.11e-01
2010-11-19 1.12e-01
2010-11-22 1.10e-01
2010-11-23 9.87e-02
2010-11-24 9.66e-02
2010-11-25 9.81e-02
2010-11-26 9.10e-02
2010-11-29 8.56e-02
2010-11-30 8.16e-02
2010-12-01 8.70e-02
2010-12-02 9.16e-02
2010-12-03 1.02e-01
2010-12-06 9.99e-02
2010-12-07 9.67e-02
2010-12-08 9.51e-02
2010-12-09 9.43e-02
2010-12-10 9.43e-02
2010-12-13 1.03e-01
2010-12-14 1.02e-01
2010-12-15 9.21e-02
2010-12-16 9.30e-02
2010-12-17 9.09e-02
2010-12-20 8.80e-02
2010-12-21 8.70e-02
2010-12-22 8.69e-02
2010-12-23 8.92e-02
2010-12-24 8.97e-02
2010-12-27 9.09e-02
2010-12-28 9.09e-02
2010-12-29 9.74e-02
2010-12-30 1.00e-01
2010-12-31 1.06e-01
2011-01-03 1.05e-01
2011-01-04 1.01e-01
2011-01-05 9.22e-02
2011-01-06 8.61e-02
2011-01-07 8.36e-02
2011-01-10 8.51e-02
2011-01-11 8.55e-02
2011-01-12 9.47e-02
2011-01-13 1.04e-01
2011-01-14 1.05e-01
2011-01-17 1.03e-01
2011-01-18 1.07e-01
2011-01-19 1.10e-01
2011-01-20 1.08e-01
2011-01-21 1.15e-01
2011-01-24 1.17e-01
2011-01-25 1.18e-01
2011-01-26 1.19e-01
2011-01-27 1.21e-01
2011-01-28 1.16e-01
2011-01-31 1.21e-01
2011-02-01 1.28e-01
2011-02-02 1.27e-01
2011-02-03 1.21e-01
2011-02-04 1.17e-01
2011-02-07 1.17e-01
2011-02-08 1.18e-01
2011-02-09 1.22e-01
2011-02-10 1.15e-01
2011-02-11 1.12e-01
2011-02-14 1.11e-01
2011-02-15 1.11e-01
2011-02-16 1.15e-01
2011-02-17 1.18e-01
2011-02-18 1.21e-01
2011-02-21 1.21e-01
2011-02-22 1.20e-01
2011-02-23 1.24e-01
2011-02-24 1.28e-01
2011-02-25 1.26e-01
2011-02-28 1.30e-01
2011-03-01 1.28e-01
2011-03-02 1.33e-01
2011-03-03 1.35e-01
2011-03-04 1.36e-01
2011-03-07 1.35e-01
2011-03-08 1.31e-01
2011-03-09 1.32e-01
2011-03-10 1.26e-01
2011-03-11 1.32e-01
2011-03-14 1.36e-01
2011-03-15 1.37e-01
2011-03-16 1.33e-01
2011-03-17 1.40e-01
2011-03-18 1.44e-01
2011-03-21 1.47e-01
2011-03-22 1.47e-01
2011-03-23 1.43e-01
2011-03-24 1.44e-01
2011-03-25 1.38e-01
2011-03-28 1.39e-01
2011-03-29 1.38e-01
2011-03-30 1.39e-01
2011-03-31 1.42e-01
2011-04-01 1.42e-01
2011-04-04 1.41e-01
2011-04-05 1.42e-01
2011-04-06 1.46e-01
2011-04-07 1.45e-01
2011-04-08 1.51e-01
2011-04-11 1.51e-01
2011-04-12 1.53e-01
2011-04-13 1.52e-01
2011-04-14 1.55e-01
2011-04-15 1.54e-01
2011-04-18 1.46e-01
2011-04-19 1.51e-01
2011-04-20 1.59e-01
2011-04-21 1.62e-01
2011-04-22 1.62e-01
2011-04-25 1.63e-01
2011-04-26 1.65e-01
2011-04-27 1.68e-01
2011-04-28 1.73e-01
2011-04-29 1.75e-01
2011-05-02 1.75e-01
2011-05-03 1.73e-01
2011-05-04 1.74e-01
2011-05-05 1.61e-01
2011-05-06 1.53e-01
2011-05-09 1.55e-01
2011-05-10 1.56e-01
2011-05-11 1.48e-01
2011-05-12 1.49e-01
2011-05-13 1.43e-01
2011-05-16 1.46e-01
2011-05-17 1.47e-01
2011-05-18 1.46e-01
2011-05-19 1.50e-01
2011-05-20 1.47e-01
2011-05-23 1.39e-01
2011-05-24 1.42e-01
2011-05-25 1.41e-01
2011-05-26 1.45e-01
2011-05-27 1.52e-01
2011-05-30 1.52e-01
2011-05-31 1.56e-01
2011-06-01 1.55e-01
2011-06-02 1.59e-01
2011-06-03 1.65e-01
2011-06-06 1.63e-01
2011-06-07 1.68e-01
2011-06-08 1.64e-01
2011-06-09 1.61e-01
2011-06-10 1.54e-01
2011-06-13 1.57e-01
2011-06-14 1.59e-01
2011-06-15 1.45e-01
2011-06-16 1.43e-01
2011-06-17 1.52e-01
2011-06-20 1.51e-01
2011-06-21 1.57e-01
2011-06-22 1.54e-01
2011-06-23 1.47e-01
2011-06-24 1.44e-01
2011-06-27 1.47e-01
2011-06-28 1.51e-01
2011-06-29 1.55e-01
2011-06-30 1.60e-01
2011-07-01 1.59e-01
2011-07-04 1.60e-01
2011-07-05 1.55e-01
2011-07-06 1.50e-01
2011-07-07 1.52e-01
2011-07-08 1.50e-01
2011-07-11 1.40e-01
2011-07-12 1.42e-01
2011-07-13 1.49e-01
2011-07-14 1.49e-01
2011-07-15 1.50e-01
2011-07-18 1.46e-01
2011-07-19 1.49e-01
2011-07-20 1.54e-01
2011-07-21 1.63e-01
2011-07-22 1.61e-01
2011-07-25 1.62e-01
2011-07-26 1.69e-01
2011-07-27 1.62e-01
2011-07-28 1.60e-01
2011-07-29 1.64e-01
2011-08-01 1.60e-01
2011-08-02 1.57e-01
2011-08-03 1.62e-01
2011-08-04 1.50e-01
2011-08-05 1.56e-01
2011-08-08 1.54e-01
2011-08-09 1.56e-01
2011-08-10 1.56e-01
2011-08-11 1.55e-01
2011-08-12 1.56e-01
2011-08-15 1.65e-01
2011-08-16 1.63e-01
2011-08-17 1.67e-01
2011-08-18 1.60e-01
2011-08-19 1.63e-01
2011-08-22 1.62e-01
2011-08-23 1.64e-01
2011-08-24 1.63e-01
2011-08-25 1.60e-01
2011-08-26 1.65e-01
2011-08-29 1.66e-01
2011-08-30 1.64e-01
2011-08-31 1.62e-01
2011-09-01 1.58e-01
2011-09-02 1.54e-01
2011-09-05 1.50e-01
2011-09-06 1.41e-01
2011-09-07 1.46e-01
2011-09-08 1.38e-01
2011-09-09 1.27e-01
2011-09-12 1.22e-01
2011-09-13 1.30e-01
2011-09-14 1.31e-01
2011-09-15 1.38e-01
2011-09-16 1.34e-01
2011-09-19 1.27e-01
2011-09-20 1.29e-01
2011-09-21 1.25e-01
2011-09-22 1.13e-01
2011-09-23 1.12e-01
2011-09-26 1.14e-01
2011-09-27 1.23e-01
2011-09-28 1.19e-01
2011-09-29 1.17e-01
2011-09-30 1.11e-01
2011-10-03 1.02e-01
2011-10-04 9.96e-02
2011-10-05 1.07e-01
2011-10-06 1.11e-01
2011-10-07 1.09e-01
2011-10-10 1.23e-01
2011-10-11 1.22e-01
2011-10-12 1.29e-01
2011-10-13 1.29e-01
2011-10-14 1.33e-01
2011-10-17 1.27e-01
2011-10-18 1.27e-01
2011-10-19 1.28e-01
2011-10-20 1.29e-01
2011-10-21 1.36e-01
2011-10-24 1.40e-01
2011-10-25 1.39e-01
2011-10-26 1.38e-01
2011-10-27 1.53e-01
2011-10-28 1.51e-01
2011-10-31 1.38e-01
2011-11-01 1.26e-01
2011-11-02 1.29e-01
2011-11-03 1.33e-01
2011-11-04 1.29e-01
2011-11-07 1.29e-01
2011-11-08 1.34e-01
2011-11-09 1.19e-01
2011-11-10 1.21e-01
2011-11-11 1.30e-01
2011-11-14 1.23e-01
2011-11-15 1.19e-01
2011-11-16 1.18e-01
2011-11-17 1.15e-01
2011-11-18 1.17e-01
2011-11-21 1.14e-01
2011-11-22 1.15e-01
2011-11-23 1.05e-01
2011-11-24 1.05e-01
2011-11-25 9.86e-02
2011-11-28 1.03e-01
2011-11-29 1.06e-01
2011-11-30 1.13e-01
2011-12-01 1.14e-01
2011-12-02 1.11e-01
2011-12-05 1.11e-01
2011-12-06 1.12e-01
2011-12-07 1.12e-01
2011-12-08 1.08e-01
2011-12-09 1.11e-01
2011-12-12 1.00e-01
2011-12-13 9.23e-02
2011-12-14 8.84e-02
2011-12-15 9.14e-02
2011-12-16 9.22e-02
2011-12-19 9.22e-02
2011-12-20 9.64e-02
2011-12-21 9.48e-02
2011-12-22 9.55e-02
2011-12-23 9.59e-02
2011-12-26 9.60e-02
2011-12-27 9.74e-02
2011-12-28 8.95e-02
2011-12-29 8.96e-02
2011-12-30 9.31e-02
2012-01-02 9.19e-02
2012-01-03 9.95e-02
2012-01-04 9.36e-02
2012-01-05 8.45e-02
2012-01-06 8.09e-02
2012-01-09 8.32e-02
2012-01-10 8.60e-02
2012-01-11 7.98e-02
2012-01-12 8.64e-02
2012-01-13 7.79e-02
2012-01-16 7.79e-02
2012-01-17 8.17e-02
2012-01-18 8.82e-02
2012-01-19 9.26e-02
2012-01-20 9.26e-02
2012-01-23 9.75e-02
2012-01-24 9.66e-02
2012-01-25 9.98e-02
2012-01-26 1.02e-01
2012-01-27 1.07e-01
2012-01-30 1.04e-01
2012-01-31 1.03e-01
2012-02-01 1.07e-01
2012-02-02 1.06e-01
2012-02-03 1.07e-01
2012-02-06 1.06e-01
2012-02-07 1.11e-01
2012-02-08 1.10e-01
2012-02-09 1.11e-01
2012-02-10 1.05e-01
2012-02-13 1.07e-01
2012-02-14 9.98e-02
2012-02-15 9.88e-02
2012-02-16 1.02e-01
2012-02-17 1.03e-01
2012-02-20 1.03e-01
2012-02-21 1.06e-01
2012-02-22 1.04e-01
2012-02-23 1.08e-01
2012-02-24 1.14e-01
2012-02-27 1.11e-01
2012-02-28 1.15e-01
2012-02-29 1.09e-01
2012-03-01 1.09e-01
2012-03-02 1.02e-01
2012-03-05 1.03e-01
2012-03-06 9.66e-02
2012-03-07 9.83e-02
2012-03-08 1.05e-01
2012-03-09 9.46e-02
2012-03-12 9.63e-02
2012-03-13 9.29e-02
2012-03-14 8.87e-02
2012-03-15 9.34e-02
2012-03-16 9.75e-02
2012-03-19 1.01e-01
2012-03-20 9.97e-02
2012-03-21 9.90e-02
2012-03-22 9.81e-02
2012-03-23 1.02e-01
2012-03-26 1.07e-01
2012-03-27 1.06e-01
2012-03-28 1.05e-01
2012-03-29 1.04e-01
2012-03-30 1.06e-01
2012-04-02 1.08e-01
2012-04-03 1.01e-01
2012-04-04 9.76e-02
2012-04-05 9.42e-02
2012-04-06 9.64e-02
2012-04-09 9.81e-02
2012-04-10 9.63e-02
2012-04-11 9.74e-02
2012-04-12 1.03e-01
2012-04-13 9.63e-02
2012-04-16 1.00e-01
2012-04-17 1.01e-01
2012-04-18 1.00e-01
2012-04-19 1.00e-01
2012-04-20 1.04e-01
2012-04-23 1.02e-01
2012-04-24 1.04e-01
2012-04-25 1.06e-01
2012-04-26 1.07e-01
2012-04-27 1.10e-01
2012-04-30 1.09e-01
2012-05-01 1.08e-01
2012-05-02 1.05e-01
2012-05-03 1.04e-01
2012-05-04 1.01e-01
2012-05-07 9.96e-02
2012-05-08 9.80e-02
2012-05-09 9.42e-02
2012-05-10 9.38e-02
2012-05-11 9.21e-02
2012-05-14 8.82e-02
2012-05-15 8.13e-02
2012-05-16 7.96e-02
2012-05-17 7.94e-02
2012-05-18 8.05e-02
2012-05-21 8.28e-02
2012-05-22 7.82e-02
2012-05-23 7.14e-02
2012-05-24 6.85e-02
2012-05-25 6.79e-02
2012-05-28 6.79e-02
2012-05-29 6.70e-02
2012-05-30 6.09e-02
2012-05-31 6.07e-02
2012-06-01 6.24e-02
2012-06-04 6.62e-02
2012-06-05 6.31e-02
2012-06-06 6.88e-02
2012-06-07 7.19e-02
2012-06-08 6.67e-02
2012-06-11 6.66e-02
2012-06-12 6.77e-02
2012-06-13 7.18e-02
2012-06-14 7.26e-02
2012-06-15 7.67e-02
2012-06-18 7.31e-02
2012-06-19 7.95e-02
2012-06-20 7.72e-02
2012-06-21 6.92e-02
2012-06-22 6.96e-02
2012-06-25 6.68e-02
2012-06-26 6.82e-02
2012-06-27 6.55e-02
2012-06-28 6.33e-02
2012-06-29 7.67e-02
2012-07-02 7.39e-02
2012-07-03 7.49e-02
2012-07-04 7.49e-02
2012-07-05 6.33e-02
2012-07-06 5.69e-02
2012-07-09 5.93e-02
2012-07-10 5.66e-02
2012-07-11 5.47e-02
2012-07-12 5.37e-02
2012-07-13 5.72e-02
2012-07-16 6.00e-02
2012-07-17 6.08e-02
2012-07-18 6.04e-02
2012-07-19 6.25e-02
2012-07-20 5.57e-02
2012-07-23 5.32e-02
2012-07-24 4.98e-02
2012-07-25 5.52e-02
2012-07-26 6.33e-02
2012-07-27 6.44e-02
2012-07-30 6.35e-02
2012-07-31 6.53e-02
2012-08-01 6.05e-02
2012-08-02 5.71e-02
2012-08-03 6.82e-02
2012-08-06 6.94e-02
2012-08-07 7.01e-02
2012-08-08 6.80e-02
2012-08-09 6.52e-02
2012-08-10 6.62e-02
2012-08-13 6.75e-02
2012-08-14 6.70e-02
2012-08-15 6.52e-02
2012-08-16 6.84e-02
2012-08-17 6.57e-02
2012-08-20 6.73e-02
2012-08-21 7.35e-02
2012-08-22 7.83e-02
2012-08-23 7.97e-02
2012-08-24 7.71e-02
2012-08-27 7.63e-02
2012-08-28 7.96e-02
2012-08-29 7.76e-02
2012-08-30 7.59e-02
2012-08-31 8.14e-02
2012-09-03 8.14e-02
2012-09-04 8.02e-02
2012-09-05 8.11e-02
2012-09-06 8.33e-02
2012-09-07 9.22e-02
2012-09-10 9.10e-02
2012-09-11 9.67e-02
2012-09-12 9.80e-02
2012-09-13 1.03e-01
2012-09-14 1.08e-01
2012-09-17 1.06e-01
2012-09-18 1.04e-01
2012-09-19 1.06e-01
2012-09-20 1.02e-01
2012-09-21 1.03e-01
2012-09-24 1.01e-01
2012-09-25 1.00e-01
2012-09-26 9.64e-02
2012-09-27 1.00e-01
2012-09-28 9.58e-02
2012-10-01 9.71e-02
2012-10-02 9.80e-02
2012-10-03 9.55e-02
2012-10-04 1.02e-01
2012-10-05 1.03e-01
2012-10-08 1.00e-01
2012-10-09 9.56e-02
2012-10-10 9.60e-02
2012-10-11 9.76e-02
2012-10-12 9.88e-02
2012-10-15 9.80e-02
2012-10-16 1.02e-01
2012-10-17 1.06e-01
2012-10-18 1.02e-01
2012-10-19 9.94e-02
2012-10-22 9.90e-02
2012-10-23 9.53e-02
2012-10-24 9.60e-02
2012-10-25 9.46e-02
2012-10-26 9.43e-02
2012-10-29 9.24e-02
2012-10-30 9.59e-02
2012-10-31 9.60e-02
2012-11-01 9.45e-02
2012-11-02 8.84e-02
2012-11-05 8.66e-02
2012-11-06 8.81e-02
2012-11-07 8.65e-02
2012-11-08 8.61e-02
2012-11-09 8.35e-02
2012-11-12 8.34e-02
2012-11-13 8.28e-02
2012-11-14 8.31e-02
2012-11-15 8.29e-02
2012-11-16 8.09e-02
2012-11-19 8.52e-02
2012-11-20 8.42e-02
2012-11-21 8.45e-02
2012-11-22 8.72e-02
2012-11-23 9.29e-02
2012-11-26 9.22e-02
2012-11-27 9.05e-02
2012-11-28 9.13e-02
2012-11-29 9.28e-02
2012-11-30 9.33e-02
2012-12-03 9.64e-02
2012-12-04 9.91e-02
2012-12-05 9.76e-02
2012-12-06 9.22e-02
2012-12-07 9.05e-02
2012-12-10 9.14e-02
2012-12-11 9.44e-02
2012-12-12 9.72e-02
2012-12-13 9.59e-02
2012-12-14 9.98e-02
2012-12-17 1.00e-01
2012-12-18 1.02e-01
2012-12-19 1.03e-01
2012-12-20 1.03e-01
2012-12-21 9.94e-02
2012-12-24 9.91e-02
2012-12-25 9.88e-02
2012-12-26 9.94e-02
2012-12-27 9.94e-02
2012-12-28 9.87e-02
2012-12-31 9.77e-02
2013-01-01 9.81e-02
2013-01-02 9.68e-02
2013-01-03 9.08e-02
2013-01-04 8.94e-02
2013-01-07 9.22e-02
2013-01-08 9.12e-02
2013-01-09 8.88e-02
2013-01-10 9.80e-02
2013-01-11 1.00e-01
2013-01-14 1.01e-01
2013-01-15 9.76e-02
2013-01-16 9.73e-02
2013-01-17 9.90e-02
2013-01-18 9.47e-02
2013-01-21 9.47e-02
2013-01-22 9.65e-02
2013-01-23 9.60e-02
2013-01-24 9.57e-02
2013-01-25 9.79e-02
2013-01-28 9.76e-02
2013-01-29 1.00e-01
2013-01-30 1.03e-01
2013-01-31 1.04e-01
2013-02-01 1.05e-01
2013-02-04 1.00e-01
2013-02-05 1.01e-01
2013-02-06 9.82e-02
2013-02-07 9.29e-02
2013-02-08 9.23e-02
2013-02-11 9.16e-02
2013-02-12 9.39e-02
2013-02-13 9.40e-02
2013-02-14 8.99e-02
2013-02-15 8.85e-02
2013-02-18 8.80e-02
2013-02-19 8.98e-02
2013-02-20 8.30e-02
2013-02-21 7.85e-02
2013-02-22 7.83e-02
2013-02-25 7.62e-02
2013-02-26 7.39e-02
2013-02-27 7.70e-02
2013-02-28 7.30e-02
2013-03-01 6.89e-02
2013-03-04 7.02e-02
2013-03-05 7.15e-02
2013-03-06 6.73e-02
2013-03-07 7.15e-02
2013-03-08 6.46e-02
2013-03-11 6.60e-02
2013-03-12 6.58e-02
2013-03-13 6.24e-02
2013-03-14 6.56e-02
2013-03-15 6.95e-02
2013-03-18 6.46e-02
2013-03-19 6.13e-02
2013-03-20 6.36e-02
2013-03-21 6.41e-02
2013-03-22 6.82e-02
2013-03-25 6.31e-02
2013-03-26 6.25e-02
2013-03-27 5.86e-02
2013-03-28 6.12e-02
2013-03-29 6.14e-02
2013-04-01 6.42e-02
2013-04-02 6.20e-02
2013-04-03 6.43e-02
2013-04-04 6.48e-02
2013-04-05 6.68e-02
2013-04-08 6.39e-02
2013-04-09 6.90e-02
2013-04-10 6.64e-02
2013-04-11 6.97e-02
2013-04-12 6.89e-02
2013-04-15 6.77e-02
2013-04-16 7.53e-02
2013-04-17 6.47e-02
2013-04-18 6.61e-02
2013-04-19 6.44e-02
2013-04-22 6.48e-02
2013-04-23 6.06e-02
2013-04-24 6.06e-02
2013-04-25 6.40e-02
2013-04-26 6.68e-02
2013-04-29 7.08e-02
2013-04-30 7.53e-02
2013-05-01 7.83e-02
2013-05-02 6.99e-02
2013-05-03 7.10e-02
2013-05-06 6.89e-02
2013-05-07 6.96e-02
2013-05-08 7.36e-02
2013-05-09 6.35e-02
2013-05-10 5.95e-02
2013-05-13 5.80e-02
2013-05-14 5.44e-02
2013-05-15 5.18e-02
2013-05-16 5.45e-02
2013-05-17 4.70e-02
2013-05-20 5.28e-02
2013-05-21 5.14e-02
2013-05-22 4.58e-02
2013-05-23 5.21e-02
2013-05-24 5.32e-02
2013-05-27 5.32e-02
2013-05-28 4.87e-02
2013-05-29 5.37e-02
2013-05-30 6.07e-02
2013-05-31 5.69e-02
2013-06-03 6.50e-02
2013-06-04 6.38e-02
2013-06-05 6.57e-02
2013-06-06 7.77e-02
2013-06-07 7.62e-02
2013-06-10 7.65e-02
2013-06-11 8.25e-02
2013-06-12 8.44e-02
2013-06-13 8.66e-02
2013-06-14 8.75e-02
2013-06-17 8.62e-02
2013-06-18 8.82e-02
2013-06-19 7.89e-02
2013-06-20 7.34e-02
2013-06-21 6.89e-02
2013-06-24 6.76e-02
2013-06-25 6.59e-02
2013-06-26 6.14e-02
2013-06-27 6.22e-02
2013-06-28 5.96e-02
2013-07-01 6.05e-02
2013-07-02 5.50e-02
2013-07-03 5.85e-02
2013-07-04 5.85e-02
2013-07-05 4.47e-02
2013-07-08 4.76e-02
2013-07-09 4.33e-02
2013-07-10 4.94e-02
2013-07-11 6.40e-02
2013-07-12 6.13e-02
2013-07-15 6.07e-02
2013-07-16 6.68e-02
2013-07-17 6.44e-02
2013-07-18 6.31e-02
2013-07-19 6.56e-02
2013-07-22 7.00e-02
2013-07-23 7.31e-02
2013-07-24 6.92e-02
2013-07-25 7.28e-02
2013-07-26 7.63e-02
2013-07-29 7.63e-02
2013-07-30 7.44e-02
2013-07-31 7.86e-02
2013-08-01 6.86e-02
2013-08-02 7.35e-02
2013-08-05 7.39e-02
2013-08-06 7.69e-02
2013-08-07 8.05e-02
2013-08-08 8.40e-02
2013-08-09 8.23e-02
2013-08-12 8.00e-02
2013-08-13 7.51e-02
2013-08-14 7.57e-02
2013-08-15 8.17e-02
2013-08-16 8.09e-02
2013-08-19 8.12e-02
2013-08-20 8.48e-02
2013-08-21 8.14e-02
2013-08-22 7.82e-02
2013-08-23 7.97e-02
2013-08-26 7.92e-02
2013-08-27 8.19e-02
2013-08-28 7.89e-02
2013-08-29 7.30e-02
2013-08-30 7.15e-02
2013-09-02 7.15e-02
2013-09-03 6.84e-02
2013-09-04 7.05e-02
2013-09-05 6.53e-02
2013-09-06 7.08e-02
2013-09-09 7.48e-02
2013-09-10 7.45e-02
2013-09-11 7.79e-02
2013-09-12 7.82e-02
2013-09-13 7.86e-02
2013-09-16 8.04e-02
2013-09-17 8.21e-02
2013-09-18 9.24e-02
2013-09-19 9.09e-02
2013-09-20 9.02e-02
2013-09-23 9.00e-02
2013-09-24 8.87e-02
2013-09-25 9.13e-02
2013-09-26 8.92e-02
2013-09-27 9.18e-02
2013-09-30 9.26e-02
2013-10-01 9.35e-02
2013-10-02 9.62e-02
2013-10-03 9.79e-02
2013-10-04 9.37e-02
2013-10-07 9.57e-02
2013-10-08 9.44e-02
2013-10-09 9.08e-02
2013-10-10 9.04e-02
2013-10-11 9.10e-02
2013-10-14 9.21e-02
2013-10-15 8.96e-02
2013-10-16 8.98e-02
2013-10-17 9.90e-02
2013-10-18 9.90e-02
2013-10-21 9.85e-02
2013-10-22 1.04e-01
2013-10-23 1.03e-01
2013-10-24 1.04e-01
2013-10-25 1.04e-01
2013-10-28 1.04e-01
2013-10-29 9.95e-02
2013-10-30 9.76e-02
2013-10-31 9.29e-02
2013-11-01 8.70e-02
2013-11-04 8.88e-02
2013-11-05 8.71e-02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `split` `ret_drawdown` along the `cumsum` of the identity of zero-valued dates. In `S` filter out the zeroes. In an `lapply` make `data.frame`s out of `min` and `max` date of the `index` of the time series as well as the sum of `a` and `rbind` and do some `rownames` cosmetics. In a last step we calculate `cumsum` `within` the resulting data frame.

```
S <- split(ret_drawdown, cumsum(ret_drawdown == 0))
S <- S[sapply(S, sum) != 0]
res <- `rownames<-`(do.call(rbind, lapply(S, function(s) 
  data.frame(start=min(index(s)), end=max(index(s)), sum=sum(s)))), NULL)
res <- within(res, {cumsum=cumsum(sum);rm(sum)})
res
#         start        end     cumsum
# 1  2010-01-07 2010-01-19  0.0823400
# 2  2010-01-20 2010-01-25  0.0852390
# 3  2010-01-29 2010-02-03  0.0947790
# 4  2010-02-05 2010-02-18  0.1290720
# 5  2010-02-19 2010-02-22  0.1307620
# 6  2010-02-23 2010-03-22  0.2438234
# 7  2010-03-25 2010-04-26  0.5163034
# 8  2010-04-28 2010-05-03  0.5284634
# 9  2010-05-06 2010-05-12  0.5481904
# 10 2010-05-18 2010-06-03  0.6477684
# 11 2010-06-07 2013-11-05 88.1295424
```

---

*Data:*

```
ret_drawdown <- structure(c(0, 0.00567, 0.0117, 0.0123, 0.0137, 0.0152, 0.00757, 
0.0109, 0.0053, 0, 0.00023, 0.000779, 0.00189, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00277, 
0.00564, 0.00113, 0, 0, 0.00173, 0.00719, 0.00513, 0.00556, 0.00277, 
0.00136, 0.00921, 0.000808, 0.000535, 0, 0.00169, 0, 1.24e-05, 
0.000779, 0.00604, 0.00237, 0.00407, 0.0108, 0.00357, 0.00517, 
0.00517, 0.00319, 0.00501, 0.00652, 0.0126, 0.00741, 0.0136, 
0.015, 0.00773, 0.00156, 0.00246, 0, 0, 0, 0.00541, 0.00928, 
0.00792, 0.0127, 0.0164, 0.0115, 0.0125, 0.00893, 0.00824, 0.00714, 
0.0125, 0.019, 0.0196, 0.0235, 0.0199, 0.0158, 0.0136, 0.013, 
0.0117, 0.00673, 0.00935, 0.00778, 0, 0, 0.00459, 0.00625, 0.00132, 
0, 0, 0, 0.00523, 0.00869, 0.00503, 0.000777, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00883, 
0.0183, 0.0205, 0.011, 0.00439, 0.00047, 0.0112, 0.00782, 0.00659, 
0.00595, 0.00423, 0.000298, 0, 0, 0.000124, 0.00575, 0.014, 0.0102, 
0.0214, 0.0274, 0.0263, 0.0307, 0.0306, 0.028, 0.026, 0.0301, 
0.0302, 0.035, 0.0311, 0.0269, 0.027, 0.0417, 0.045, 0.043, 0.0489, 
0.0518, 0.0518, 0.0504, 0.0475, 0.0539, 0.0563, 0.0661, 0.067, 
0.0666, 0.064, 0.0567, 0.0657, 0.0672, 0.0715, 0.0704, 0.0704, 
0.0766, 0.0777, 0.0845, 0.0883, 0.085, 0.0857, 0.0905, 0.087, 
0.086, 0.0692, 0.0653, 0.0617, 0.0664, 0.0699, 0.0699, 0.0674, 
0.0605, 0.0597, 0.0595, 0.0582, 0.0619, 0.0621, 0.0593, 0.0589, 
0.0665, 0.0672, 0.0713, 0.072, 0.0632, 0.0658, 0.0648, 0.0646, 
0.0734, 0.0829, 0.0782, 0.081, 0.0793, 0.08, 0.0901, 0.097, 0.095, 
0.102, 0.103, 0.106, 0.11, 0.11, 0.117, 0.113, 0.121, 0.125, 
0.125, 0.125, 0.124, 0.125, 0.128, 0.133, 0.129, 0.13, 0.116, 
0.127, 0.124, 0.124, 0.128, 0.121, 0.116, 0.126, 0.126, 0.126, 
0.132, 0.135, 0.142, 0.134, 0.129, 0.124, 0.122, 0.115, 0.117, 
0.112, 0.104, 0.105, 0.111, 0.112, 0.11, 0.0987, 0.0966, 0.0981, 
0.091, 0.0856, 0.0816, 0.087, 0.0916, 0.102, 0.0999, 0.0967, 
0.0951, 0.0943, 0.0943, 0.103, 0.102, 0.0921, 0.093, 0.0909, 
0.088, 0.087, 0.0869, 0.0892, 0.0897, 0.0909, 0.0909, 0.0974, 
0.1, 0.106, 0.105, 0.101, 0.0922, 0.0861, 0.0836, 0.0851, 0.0855, 
0.0947, 0.104, 0.105, 0.103, 0.107, 0.11, 0.108, 0.115, 0.117, 
0.118, 0.119, 0.121, 0.116, 0.121, 0.128, 0.127, 0.121, 0.117, 
0.117, 0.118, 0.122, 0.115, 0.112, 0.111, 0.111, 0.115, 0.118, 
0.121, 0.121, 0.12, 0.124, 0.128, 0.126, 0.13, 0.128, 0.133, 
0.135, 0.136, 0.135, 0.131, 0.132, 0.126, 0.132, 0.136, 0.137, 
0.133, 0.14, 0.144, 0.147, 0.147, 0.143, 0.144, 0.138, 0.139, 
0.138, 0.139, 0.142, 0.142, 0.141, 0.142, 0.146, 0.145, 0.151, 
0.151, 0.153, 0.152, 0.155, 0.154, 0.146, 0.151, 0.159, 0.162, 
0.162, 0.163, 0.165, 0.168, 0.173, 0.175, 0.175, 0.173, 0.174, 
0.161, 0.153, 0.155, 0.156, 0.148, 0.149, 0.143, 0.146, 0.147, 
0.146, 0.15, 0.147, 0.139, 0.142, 0.141, 0.145, 0.152, 0.152, 
0.156, 0.155, 0.159, 0.165, 0.163, 0.168, 0.164, 0.161, 0.154, 
0.157, 0.159, 0.145, 0.143, 0.152, 0.151, 0.157, 0.154, 0.147, 
0.144, 0.147, 0.151, 0.155, 0.16, 0.159, 0.16, 0.155, 0.15, 0.152, 
0.15, 0.14, 0.142, 0.149, 0.149, 0.15, 0.146, 0.149, 0.154, 0.163, 
0.161, 0.162, 0.169, 0.162, 0.16, 0.164, 0.16, 0.157, 0.162, 
0.15, 0.156, 0.154, 0.156, 0.156, 0.155, 0.156, 0.165, 0.163, 
0.167, 0.16, 0.163, 0.162, 0.164, 0.163, 0.16, 0.165, 0.166, 
0.164, 0.162, 0.158, 0.154, 0.15, 0.141, 0.146, 0.138, 0.127, 
0.122, 0.13, 0.131, 0.138, 0.134, 0.127, 0.129, 0.125, 0.113, 
0.112, 0.114, 0.123, 0.119, 0.117, 0.111, 0.102, 0.0996, 0.107, 
0.111, 0.109, 0.123, 0.122, 0.129, 0.129, 0.133, 0.127, 0.127, 
0.128, 0.129, 0.136, 0.14, 0.139, 0.138, 0.153, 0.151, 0.138, 
0.126, 0.129, 0.133, 0.129, 0.129, 0.134, 0.119, 0.121, 0.13, 
0.123, 0.119, 0.118, 0.115, 0.117, 0.114, 0.115, 0.105, 0.105, 
0.0986, 0.103, 0.106, 0.113, 0.114, 0.111, 0.111, 0.112, 0.112, 
0.108, 0.111, 0.1, 0.0923, 0.0884, 0.0914, 0.0922, 0.0922, 0.0964, 
0.0948, 0.0955, 0.0959, 0.096, 0.0974, 0.0895, 0.0896, 0.0931, 
0.0919, 0.0995, 0.0936, 0.0845, 0.0809, 0.0832, 0.086, 0.0798, 
0.0864, 0.0779, 0.0779, 0.0817, 0.0882, 0.0926, 0.0926, 0.0975, 
0.0966, 0.0998, 0.102, 0.107, 0.104, 0.103, 0.107, 0.106, 0.107, 
0.106, 0.111, 0.11, 0.111, 0.105, 0.107, 0.0998, 0.0988, 0.102, 
0.103, 0.103, 0.106, 0.104, 0.108, 0.114, 0.111, 0.115, 0.109, 
0.109, 0.102, 0.103, 0.0966, 0.0983, 0.105, 0.0946, 0.0963, 0.0929, 
0.0887, 0.0934, 0.0975, 0.101, 0.0997, 0.099, 0.0981, 0.102, 
0.107, 0.106, 0.105, 0.104, 0.106, 0.108, 0.101, 0.0976, 0.0942, 
0.0964, 0.0981, 0.0963, 0.0974, 0.103, 0.0963, 0.1, 0.101, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.104, 0.102, 0.104, 0.106, 0.107, 0.11, 0.109, 0.108, 0.105, 
0.104, 0.101, 0.0996, 0.098, 0.0942, 0.0938, 0.0921, 0.0882, 
0.0813, 0.0796, 0.0794, 0.0805, 0.0828, 0.0782, 0.0714, 0.0685, 
0.0679, 0.0679, 0.067, 0.0609, 0.0607, 0.0624, 0.0662, 0.0631, 
0.0688, 0.0719, 0.0667, 0.0666, 0.0677, 0.0718, 0.0726, 0.0767, 
0.0731, 0.0795, 0.0772, 0.0692, 0.0696, 0.0668, 0.0682, 0.0655, 
0.0633, 0.0767, 0.0739, 0.0749, 0.0749, 0.0633, 0.0569, 0.0593, 
0.0566, 0.0547, 0.0537, 0.0572, 0.06, 0.0608, 0.0604, 0.0625, 
0.0557, 0.0532, 0.0498, 0.0552, 0.0633, 0.0644, 0.0635, 0.0653, 
0.0605, 0.0571, 0.0682, 0.0694, 0.0701, 0.068, 0.0652, 0.0662, 
0.0675, 0.067, 0.0652, 0.0684, 0.0657, 0.0673, 0.0735, 0.0783, 
0.0797, 0.0771, 0.0763, 0.0796, 0.0776, 0.0759, 0.0814, 0.0814, 
0.0802, 0.0811, 0.0833, 0.0922, 0.091, 0.0967, 0.098, 0.103, 
0.108, 0.106, 0.104, 0.106, 0.102, 0.103, 0.101, 0.1, 0.0964, 
0.1, 0.0958, 0.0971, 0.098, 0.0955, 0.102, 0.103, 0.1, 0.0956, 
0.096, 0.0976, 0.0988, 0.098, 0.102, 0.106, 0.102, 0.0994, 0.099, 
0.0953, 0.096, 0.0946, 0.0943, 0.0924, 0.0959, 0.096, 0.0945, 
0.0884, 0.0866, 0.0881, 0.0865, 0.0861, 0.0835, 0.0834, 0.0828, 
0.0831, 0.0829, 0.0809, 0.0852, 0.0842, 0.0845, 0.0872, 0.0929, 
0.0922, 0.0905, 0.0913, 0.0928, 0.0933, 0.0964, 0.0991, 0.0976, 
0.0922, 0.0905, 0.0914, 0.0944, 0.0972, 0.0959, 0.0998, 0.1, 
0.102, 0.103, 0.103, 0.0994, 0.0991, 0.0988, 0.0994, 0.0994, 
0.0987, 0.0977, 0.0981, 0.0968, 0.0908, 0.0894, 0.0922, 0.0912, 
0.0888, 0.098, 0.1, 0.101, 0.0976, 0.0973, 0.099, 0.0947, 0.0947, 
0.0965, 0.096, 0.0957, 0.0979, 0.0976, 0.1, 0.103, 0.104, 0.105, 
0.1, 0.101, 0.0982, 0.0929, 0.0923, 0.0916, 0.0939, 0.094, 0.0899, 
0.0885, 0.088, 0.0898, 0.083, 0.0785, 0.0783, 0.0762, 0.0739, 
0.077, 0.073, 0.0689, 0.0702, 0.0715, 0.0673, 0.0715, 0.0646, 
0.066, 0.0658, 0.0624, 0.0656, 0.0695, 0.0646, 0.0613, 0.0636, 
0.0641, 0.0682, 0.0631, 0.0625, 0.0586, 0.0612, 0.0614, 0.0642, 
0.062, 0.0643, 0.0648, 0.0668, 0.0639, 0.069, 0.0664, 0.0697, 
0.0689, 0.0677, 0.0753, 0.0647, 0.0661, 0.0644, 0.0648, 0.0606, 
0.0606, 0.064, 0.0668, 0.0708, 0.0753, 0.0783, 0.0699, 0.071, 
0.0689, 0.0696, 0.0736, 0.0635, 0.0595, 0.058, 0.0544, 0.0518, 
0.0545, 0.047, 0.0528, 0.0514, 0.0458, 0.0521, 0.0532, 0.0532, 
0.0487, 0.0537, 0.0607, 0.0569, 0.065, 0.0638, 0.0657, 0.0777, 
0.0762, 0.0765, 0.0825, 0.0844, 0.0866, 0.0875, 0.0862, 0.0882, 
0.0789, 0.0734, 0.0689, 0.0676, 0.0659, 0.0614, 0.0622, 0.0596, 
0.0605, 0.055, 0.0585, 0.0585, 0.0447, 0.0476, 0.0433, 0.0494, 
0.064, 0.0613, 0.0607, 0.0668, 0.0644, 0.0631, 0.0656, 0.07, 
0.0731, 0.0692, 0.0728, 0.0763, 0.0763, 0.0744, 0.0786, 0.0686, 
0.0735, 0.0739, 0.0769, 0.0805, 0.084, 0.0823, 0.08, 0.0751, 
0.0757, 0.0817, 0.0809, 0.0812, 0.0848, 0.0814, 0.0782, 0.0797, 
0.0792, 0.0819, 0.0789, 0.073, 0.0715, 0.0715, 0.0684, 0.0705, 
0.0653, 0.0708, 0.0748, 0.0745, 0.0779, 0.0782, 0.0786, 0.0804, 
0.0821, 0.0924, 0.0909, 0.0902, 0.09, 0.0887, 0.0913, 0.0892, 
0.0918, 0.0926, 0.0935, 0.0962, 0.0979, 0.0937, 0.0957, 0.0944, 
0.0908, 0.0904, 0.091, 0.0921, 0.0896, 0.0898, 0.099, 0.099, 
0.0985, 0.104, 0.103, 0.104, 0.104, 0.104, 0.0995, 0.0976, 0.0929, 
0.087, 0.0888, 0.0871), .Dim = c(999L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, "V2"), index = structure(c(1262818800, 1262905200, 
1263164400, 1263250800, 1263337200, 1263423600, 1263510000, 1263769200, 
1263855600, 1263942000, 1264028400, 1264114800, 1264374000, 1264460400, 
1264546800, 1264633200, 1264719600, 1264978800, 1265065200, 1265151600, 
1265238000, 1265324400, 1265583600, 1265670000, 1265756400, 1265842800, 
1265929200, 1266188400, 1266274800, 1266361200, 1266447600, 1266534000, 
1266793200, 1266879600, 1266966000, 1267052400, 1267138800, 1267398000, 
1267484400, 1267570800, 1267657200, 1267743600, 1268002800, 1268089200, 
1268175600, 1268262000, 1268348400, 1268607600, 1268694000, 1268780400, 
1268866800, 1268953200, 1269212400, 1269298800, 1269385200, 1269471600, 
1269558000, 1269813600, 1269900000, 1269986400, 1270072800, 1270159200, 
1270418400, 1270504800, 1270591200, 1270677600, 1270764000, 1271023200, 
1271109600, 1271196000, 1271282400, 1271368800, 1271628000, 1271714400, 
1271800800, 1271887200, 1271973600, 1272232800, 1272319200, 1272405600, 
1272492000, 1272578400, 1272837600, 1272924000, 1273010400, 1273096800, 
1273183200, 1273442400, 1273528800, 1273615200, 1273701600, 1273788000, 
1274047200, 1274133600, 1274220000, 1274306400, 1274392800, 1274652000, 
1274738400, 1274824800, 1274911200, 1274997600, 1275256800, 1275343200, 
1275429600, 1275516000, 1275602400, 1275861600, 1275948000, 1276034400, 
1276120800, 1276207200, 1276466400, 1276552800, 1276639200, 1276725600, 
1276812000, 1277071200, 1277157600, 1277244000, 1277330400, 1277416800, 
1277676000, 1277762400, 1277848800, 1277935200, 1278021600, 1278280800, 
1278367200, 1278453600, 1278540000, 1278626400, 1278885600, 1278972000, 
1279058400, 1279144800, 1279231200, 1279490400, 1279576800, 1279663200, 
1279749600, 1279836000, 1280095200, 1280181600, 1280268000, 1280354400, 
1280440800, 1280700000, 1280786400, 1280872800, 1280959200, 1281045600, 
1281304800, 1281391200, 1281477600, 1281564000, 1281650400, 1281909600, 
1281996000, 1282082400, 1282168800, 1282255200, 1282514400, 1282600800, 
1282687200, 1282773600, 1282860000, 1283119200, 1283205600, 1283292000, 
1283378400, 1283464800, 1283724000, 1283810400, 1283896800, 1283983200, 
1284069600, 1284328800, 1284415200, 1284501600, 1284588000, 1284674400, 
1284933600, 1285020000, 1285106400, 1285192800, 1285279200, 1285538400, 
1285624800, 1285711200, 1285797600, 1285884000, 1286143200, 1286229600, 
1286316000, 1286402400, 1286488800, 1286748000, 1286834400, 1286920800, 
1287007200, 1287093600, 1287352800, 1287439200, 1287525600, 1287612000, 
1287698400, 1287957600, 1288044000, 1288130400, 1288216800, 1288303200, 
1288566000, 1288652400, 1288738800, 1288825200, 1288911600, 1289170800, 
1289257200, 1289343600, 1289430000, 1289516400, 1289775600, 1289862000, 
1289948400, 1290034800, 1290121200, 1290380400, 1290466800, 1290553200, 
1290639600, 1290726000, 1290985200, 1291071600, 1291158000, 1291244400, 
1291330800, 1291590000, 1291676400, 1291762800, 1291849200, 1291935600, 
1292194800, 1292281200, 1292367600, 1292454000, 1292540400, 1292799600, 
1292886000, 1292972400, 1293058800, 1293145200, 1293404400, 1293490800, 
1293577200, 1293663600, 1293750000, 1294009200, 1294095600, 1294182000, 
1294268400, 1294354800, 1294614000, 1294700400, 1294786800, 1294873200, 
1294959600, 1295218800, 1295305200, 1295391600, 1295478000, 1295564400, 
1295823600, 1295910000, 1295996400, 1296082800, 1296169200, 1296428400, 
1296514800, 1296601200, 1296687600, 1296774000, 1297033200, 1297119600, 
1297206000, 1297292400, 1297378800, 1297638000, 1297724400, 1297810800, 
1297897200, 1297983600, 1298242800, 1298329200, 1298415600, 1298502000, 
1298588400, 1298847600, 1298934000, 1299020400, 1299106800, 1299193200, 
1299452400, 1299538800, 1299625200, 1299711600, 1299798000, 1300057200, 
1300143600, 1300230000, 1300316400, 1300402800, 1300662000, 1300748400, 
1300834800, 1300921200, 1301007600, 1301263200, 1301349600, 1301436000, 
1301522400, 1301608800, 1301868000, 1301954400, 1302040800, 1302127200, 
1302213600, 1302472800, 1302559200, 1302645600, 1302732000, 1302818400, 
1303077600, 1303164000, 1303250400, 1303336800, 1303423200, 1303682400, 
1303768800, 1303855200, 1303941600, 1304028000, 1304287200, 1304373600, 
1304460000, 1304546400, 1304632800, 1304892000, 1304978400, 1305064800, 
1305151200, 1305237600, 1305496800, 1305583200, 1305669600, 1305756000, 
1305842400, 1306101600, 1306188000, 1306274400, 1306360800, 1306447200, 
1306706400, 1306792800, 1306879200, 1306965600, 1307052000, 1307311200, 
1307397600, 1307484000, 1307570400, 1307656800, 1307916000, 1308002400, 
1308088800, 1308175200, 1308261600, 1308520800, 1308607200, 1308693600, 
1308780000, 1308866400, 1309125600, 1309212000, 1309298400, 1309384800, 
1309471200, 1309730400, 1309816800, 1309903200, 1309989600, 1310076000, 
1310335200, 1310421600, 1310508000, 1310594400, 1310680800, 1310940000, 
1311026400, 1311112800, 1311199200, 1311285600, 1311544800, 1311631200, 
1311717600, 1311804000, 1311890400, 1312149600, 1312236000, 1312322400, 
1312408800, 1312495200, 1312754400, 1312840800, 1312927200, 1313013600, 
1313100000, 1313359200, 1313445600, 1313532000, 1313618400, 1313704800, 
1313964000, 1314050400, 1314136800, 1314223200, 1314309600, 1314568800, 
1314655200, 1314741600, 1314828000, 1314914400, 1315173600, 1315260000, 
1315346400, 1315432800, 1315519200, 1315778400, 1315864800, 1315951200, 
1316037600, 1316124000, 1316383200, 1316469600, 1316556000, 1316642400, 
1316728800, 1316988000, 1317074400, 1317160800, 1317247200, 1317333600, 
1317592800, 1317679200, 1317765600, 1317852000, 1317938400, 1318197600, 
1318284000, 1318370400, 1318456800, 1318543200, 1318802400, 1318888800, 
1318975200, 1319061600, 1319148000, 1319407200, 1319493600, 1319580000, 
1319666400, 1319752800, 1320015600, 1320102000, 1320188400, 1320274800, 
1320361200, 1320620400, 1320706800, 1320793200, 1320879600, 1320966000, 
1321225200, 1321311600, 1321398000, 1321484400, 1321570800, 1321830000, 
1321916400, 1322002800, 1322089200, 1322175600, 1322434800, 1322521200, 
1322607600, 1322694000, 1322780400, 1323039600, 1323126000, 1323212400, 
1323298800, 1323385200, 1323644400, 1323730800, 1323817200, 1323903600, 
1323990000, 1324249200, 1324335600, 1324422000, 1324508400, 1324594800, 
1324854000, 1324940400, 1325026800, 1325113200, 1325199600, 1325458800, 
1325545200, 1325631600, 1325718000, 1325804400, 1326063600, 1326150000, 
1326236400, 1326322800, 1326409200, 1326668400, 1326754800, 1326841200, 
1326927600, 1327014000, 1327273200, 1327359600, 1327446000, 1327532400, 
1327618800, 1327878000, 1327964400, 1328050800, 1328137200, 1328223600, 
1328482800, 1328569200, 1328655600, 1328742000, 1328828400, 1329087600, 
1329174000, 1329260400, 1329346800, 1329433200, 1329692400, 1329778800, 
1329865200, 1329951600, 1330038000, 1330297200, 1330383600, 1330470000, 
1330556400, 1330642800, 1330902000, 1330988400, 1331074800, 1331161200, 
1331247600, 1331506800, 1331593200, 1331679600, 1331766000, 1331852400, 
1332111600, 1332198000, 1332284400, 1332370800, 1332457200, 1332712800, 
1332799200, 1332885600, 1332972000, 1333058400, 1333317600, 1333404000, 
1333490400, 1333576800, 1333663200, 1333922400, 1334008800, 1334095200, 
1334181600, 1334268000, 1334527200, 1334613600, 1334700000, 1334786400, 
1334872800, 1335132000, 1335218400, 1335304800, 1335391200, 1335477600, 
1335736800, 1335823200, 1335909600, 1335996000, 1336082400, 1336341600, 
1336428000, 1336514400, 1336600800, 1336687200, 1336946400, 1337032800, 
1337119200, 1337205600, 1337292000, 1337551200, 1337637600, 1337724000, 
1337810400, 1337896800, 1338156000, 1338242400, 1338328800, 1338415200, 
1338501600, 1338760800, 1338847200, 1338933600, 1339020000, 1339106400, 
1339365600, 1339452000, 1339538400, 1339624800, 1339711200, 1339970400, 
1340056800, 1340143200, 1340229600, 1340316000, 1340575200, 1340661600, 
1340748000, 1340834400, 1340920800, 1341180000, 1341266400, 1341352800, 
1341439200, 1341525600, 1341784800, 1341871200, 1341957600, 1342044000, 
1342130400, 1342389600, 1342476000, 1342562400, 1342648800, 1342735200, 
1342994400, 1343080800, 1343167200, 1343253600, 1343340000, 1343599200, 
1343685600, 1343772000, 1343858400, 1343944800, 1344204000, 1344290400, 
1344376800, 1344463200, 1344549600, 1344808800, 1344895200, 1344981600, 
1345068000, 1345154400, 1345413600, 1345500000, 1345586400, 1345672800, 
1345759200, 1346018400, 1346104800, 1346191200, 1346277600, 1346364000, 
1346623200, 1346709600, 1346796000, 1346882400, 1346968800, 1347228000, 
1347314400, 1347400800, 1347487200, 1347573600, 1347832800, 1347919200, 
1348005600, 1348092000, 1348178400, 1348437600, 1348524000, 1348610400, 
1348696800, 1348783200, 1349042400, 1349128800, 1349215200, 1349301600, 
1349388000, 1349647200, 1349733600, 1349820000, 1349906400, 1349992800, 
1350252000, 1350338400, 1350424800, 1350511200, 1350597600, 1350856800, 
1350943200, 1351029600, 1351116000, 1351202400, 1351465200, 1351551600, 
1351638000, 1351724400, 1351810800, 1352070000, 1352156400, 1352242800, 
1352329200, 1352415600, 1352674800, 1352761200, 1352847600, 1352934000, 
1353020400, 1353279600, 1353366000, 1353452400, 1353538800, 1353625200, 
1353884400, 1353970800, 1354057200, 1354143600, 1354230000, 1354489200, 
1354575600, 1354662000, 1354748400, 1354834800, 1355094000, 1355180400, 
1355266800, 1355353200, 1355439600, 1355698800, 1355785200, 1355871600, 
1355958000, 1356044400, 1356303600, 1356390000, 1356476400, 1356562800, 
1356649200, 1356908400, 1356994800, 1357081200, 1357167600, 1357254000, 
1357513200, 1357599600, 1357686000, 1357772400, 1357858800, 1358118000, 
1358204400, 1358290800, 1358377200, 1358463600, 1358722800, 1358809200, 
1358895600, 1358982000, 1359068400, 1359327600, 1359414000, 1359500400, 
1359586800, 1359673200, 1359932400, 1360018800, 1360105200, 1360191600, 
1360278000, 1360537200, 1360623600, 1360710000, 1360796400, 1360882800, 
1361142000, 1361228400, 1361314800, 1361401200, 1361487600, 1361746800, 
1361833200, 1361919600, 1362006000, 1362092400, 1362351600, 1362438000, 
1362524400, 1362610800, 1362697200, 1362956400, 1363042800, 1363129200, 
1363215600, 1363302000, 1363561200, 1363647600, 1363734000, 1363820400, 
1363906800, 1364166000, 1364252400, 1364338800, 1364425200, 1364511600, 
1364767200, 1364853600, 1364940000, 1365026400, 1365112800, 1365372000, 
1365458400, 1365544800, 1365631200, 1365717600, 1365976800, 1366063200, 
1366149600, 1366236000, 1366322400, 1366581600, 1366668000, 1366754400, 
1366840800, 1366927200, 1367186400, 1367272800, 1367359200, 1367445600, 
1367532000, 1367791200, 1367877600, 1367964000, 1368050400, 1368136800, 
1368396000, 1368482400, 1368568800, 1368655200, 1368741600, 1369000800, 
1369087200, 1369173600, 1369260000, 1369346400, 1369605600, 1369692000, 
1369778400, 1369864800, 1369951200, 1370210400, 1370296800, 1370383200, 
1370469600, 1370556000, 1370815200, 1370901600, 1370988000, 1371074400, 
1371160800, 1371420000, 1371506400, 1371592800, 1371679200, 1371765600, 
1372024800, 1372111200, 1372197600, 1372284000, 1372370400, 1372629600, 
1372716000, 1372802400, 1372888800, 1372975200, 1373234400, 1373320800, 
1373407200, 1373493600, 1373580000, 1373839200, 1373925600, 1374012000, 
1374098400, 1374184800, 1374444000, 1374530400, 1374616800, 1374703200, 
1374789600, 1375048800, 1375135200, 1375221600, 1375308000, 1375394400, 
1375653600, 1375740000, 1375826400, 1375912800, 1375999200, 1376258400, 
1376344800, 1376431200, 1376517600, 1376604000, 1376863200, 1376949600, 
1377036000, 1377122400, 1377208800, 1377468000, 1377554400, 1377640800, 
1377727200, 1377813600, 1378072800, 1378159200, 1378245600, 1378332000, 
1378418400, 1378677600, 1378764000, 1378850400, 1378936800, 1379023200, 
1379282400, 1379368800, 1379455200, 1379541600, 1379628000, 1379887200, 
1379973600, 1380060000, 1380146400, 1380232800, 1380492000, 1380578400, 
1380664800, 1380751200, 1380837600, 1381096800, 1381183200, 1381269600, 
1381356000, 1381442400, 1381701600, 1381788000, 1381874400, 1381960800, 
1382047200, 1382306400, 1382392800, 1382479200, 1382565600, 1382652000, 
1382914800, 1383001200, 1383087600, 1383174000, 1383260400, 1383519600, 
1383606000), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))
```

Comment: What is variable x here. rh1 or ret_drawdown ?

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni Ah sorry, I substituted `x` for `ret_drawdown[ret_drawdown != 0]`, see update.

Comment: Somehow, it's not working for generic case.

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni Yeah, you need to understand the method and adapt it to your generic data (which I don't know). Or at least edit your question to show as an example what doesn't work.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: I understood your solution by assigning each step to a variable. However, the dates seem to overlap when the solution is implemented on the new data set

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni Try now, code should scale better now.

Comment: Okay, will wait.

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni Ok, see update if it scales to your original data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228589/discussion-between-abhishek-kulkarni-and-jay-sf).